# Getting bounds for Leaflet ImageOverlay

Tags: leaflet

Here's a mapbox example of using Leaflet image overlay: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/imageoverlay-georeferenced/

Say I got a custom map, and I want to overlay an image on it. How would I go about getting the bounds for the location I want to put it in. How would I maintain the aspect ratio of the image?

Comment: As workaround, I just set map container width and height in order to maintain the image ratio, just before calling `L.map(...)`